# Create a table with auto_increment based on a different column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Basically the title states what I am trying to do. The mysql manual outlines how it should work here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

I think, however, I must be missing something obvious as it is not working for me.  Here is my code:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    block VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    issue_number MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date BIGINT(30),
    UNIQUE (id),
    PRIMARY KEY  (block, issue_number)
);";
```

Comment: You cannot have 2 AUTO_INCREMENT in one Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no posibilites to have more than one autoincrement columns in one table. Use this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL,
    block VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    issue_number MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date BIGINT(30),
    UNIQUE (id),
    PRIMARY KEY  (block, issue_number)
);"
```

Comment: But according to your SQL id colmn is UNIQUE, and complex index will be malfunction

Comment: I just have to manually increment the id based upon the previous value. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key, below one is working

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    block VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    issue_number MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL ,
    date BIGINT(30),
    UNIQUE (id),
    PRIMARY KEY  (block, issue_number)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, only one auto_increment -column is allowed. You could try to increment your id in insert-statement.

```
insert into $table_name (id) values (1) on duplicate key update id = id + 1;
```

but perhaps not the best solution..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MyISAM table with auto incremented `issue_number` field, e.g. -

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  id MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL,
  block VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  issue_number MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date BIGINT(30),
  UNIQUE (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (block, issue_number)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM;
```